# Replacing the (add to compare list link) with the checkbox

Tags: flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Flags Link into a Checkbox](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/convert-a-flags-link-into-a-checkbox)

How we can replace the (add to compare list link) with the checkbox in drupal 7. while using flag module.

Comment: Please provide more information on what do you have, and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes this Same As Convert A flags Link Into A checkox .Then I want To Know Where I have To place That Jquery Code. or any Other Method For Doing that.

Comment: @Chapabu I have Checked That Solution But Does't Work.